# ADB "offline" for Kindle Fire debugging, or freezes Android Studio?

Tags: android, adb, kindle-fire

Lots of problems trying to debug my app on Kindle Fire (HDX 8.9 4th Gen)

If I start adb from the command line, adb devices shows the device connected as "device", but if I then try to debug my app, Android Studio freezes, and won't unfreeze until I adb kill-server.

Once i've killed the server, I can start the debug, but when adb pops the pick device dialog, it shows the kindleFire device as offline and also incompatible (showing SDK for the device as 1).

I have tried many fixes proposed here and elsewhere including making sure ADB is updated, making sure Kindlefire drivers have been loaded (several times) turning off and on adb on the device, killing and restarting ADB from the command line, checking the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable and looking for multiple copies of adb.exe.  No joy on any of those.

I never manage to see the "confirm fingerprint" dialog either.

Interestingly, it seems to work OK with my firephone, but doesn't with work either of two KindleFire tables (the big one or the small one.)

Anybody have any ideas?